# Is it possible to associate particular filename to an application

Tags: windows, file-association

Say I'd like to open any `Makefile` with MS `notepad`. Is it to make such an association?

Binding `notepad` to any file without suffix is not a nice solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an extension to your makefile and bind that type to notepad, could be something like `.mkf`, but do you really need that association?. If your using any command line you could edit the file executing `notepad MakeFile`.

Comment: what if I download someone else's code? anyway, it's a optimization